# Check if port 57875 is closed on localhost VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, connection, portforwarding

I am trying to see if port 57875 on localhost, the computer, is closed.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
Try
        Dim checkPort As TcpClient = New TcpClient("localhost", 57875)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("WARNING: Port 57875 is not forwarded ! The game will probably encounter an error !")
    End Try
```

Even if it is forwarded, it will think it isn't. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What does port forwarding mean here? Usually PF means, that your ROUTER sends incoming (from WAN) packets for port XY to IP_whatever (on LAN) and port YZ (which might be equal to XY or not). Connecting LOCALLY to port YZ doesnt tell you, if the port (in the router) is forwarded.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example:

```
Dim host As String = "localhost"

Dim port As Integer = 57875

Dim addr As IPAddress = DirectCast(Dns.GetHostAddresses(host)(0), IPAddress)

Try   

    Dim tcpList As New TcpListener(addr, port)   
    tcpList.Start()

Catch sx As SocketException
  'Catch exception - No available port
End Try
```

Comment: That is not possible. I've tried it. Make a telnet to localhost 57875 and see what is the output